# Is there a function or way to determine which files of a package are being used in python?

Tags: python, file, libraries, vpython

I'm currently working on a project which uses VPython and I'd like to look into the library's source code. The only problem is that I'm unsure which VPython files are being used when I use VPython in my own script. I would like to be able to see what files are being run when I import and use VPython.

Answer (score 0):

The repo is https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter

Also, see the files in ...Lib/site-packages/vpython

Also possibly of interest is this brief description of the architecture of VPython:

https://vpython.org/contents/VPythonArchitecture.pdf

Here is a lengthy, detailed discussion of VPython architecture:

https://github.com/vpython/glowscript/blob/master/docs/GlowScriptOverview.md